# How to remove the unwanted mark from date input field?

Tags: html, css, date, input, styles

[image]

I need remove the x mark from the input, I use boostrap 4

This is the Code

```
 <div class="form-group">
                    <center>Ingresa tu fecha de nacimiento</center>
                    <br>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="bday" placeholder="Ingresa tu fecha de nacimiento" value="{{bday}}" style="text-align: center">
                </div>
```

I want the x and arrows to be erased

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the psuedo-class here

In CSS put this code

```
input[type=date]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    display: none;
}
```

then for the input tag you need to add `required` like this

```
 <input type='date' required>
```